# In R flextable can complex symbols appear in column headings

Tags: r, flextable

Using `flextable` to make a table, I would like a column heading to be pi (with a hat) and an i subscript.  With `flextable` 6 I [see](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html) that I can add basic formatting to titles using the `compose()` function. I can get pi sub i easily but I don't see how to put the hat over the pi.

```
test <- data.frame(hat_pi_i= c(0.1, 0.9))

# devtools::install_github("davidgohel/flextable")  # version 6.x
# devtools::install_github("davidgohel/officer")  # for flextable 6 to work

library(flextable)
# compose conflicts with purrr & igraph
flextable(test) %>% 
  compose(part = "header", j = "hat_pi_i", 
          value = as_paragraph("hat π", as_sub("i")))
```

Is it possible to tweak the title above to put the hat on the pi instead of as a word next to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a hackish way to do it:

```
flextable(test) %>% 
  compose(part = "header", j = "hat_pi_i", 
          value = as_paragraph("\U1D70B\U0302", as_sub("i")))
```

[image: screenshot]

This uses Unicode characters:  `\U1D70B` is the math style pi, and `\U0302` says to put a circumflex on the previous character.  You could also do the first char with `π`, but it doesn't look as good, because (at least on my system) the circumflex ends up misplaced:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you.  That renders beautifully on my machine.